# Using subscript operator within a class on a template array

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

```
..
..
..

const int sizes = 50;

template<class T>
class List {
private:
    int curSize;
    T arr[sizes];

public:
    List<T>(){
        cout << "constructor called\n";
        this->curSize = 0;
    }

    void add(T element) {
        arr[curSize] = element;
        this->curSize++;
    }

..
..
..

T operator[](int i){
        if( i > sizes ){
            cout << "Index out of bounds" << endl;
            return arr[0];
        }
        return arr[i];
}
```

when i call the add function the operator overloading isnt working for me, only when i try to acces it from the main.cpp it works.
how can i acces the operator inside the class?
i searched here and i found a soulotion that didnt worked for me (*this).

Comment: Are you expecting `arr[curSize]` to call `T operator[](int i)`?

Comment: The `add` function uses the `[]` operator on `arr`, which isn't an instance of your class, so the overloaded operator isn't called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you found using `(*this)` was correct but your `operator[]` returns the wrong type so there would be no correct way to use it.  Change the return from `T` to `T&`:

```
T& operator[](int i){
        if( i > sizes || i<0 ){
            cout << "Index out of bounds" << endl;
            return arr[0];
        }
        return arr[i];
}
```

Then you can use it inside your class with:

```
(*this)[curSize] = element;
```

You should also have a const version:

```
T const& operator[](int i) const {
        if( i > sizes || i<0 ){
            cout << "Index out of bounds" << endl;
            return arr[0];
        }
        return arr[i];
}
```

An alternate way to code the const and non const versions (to avoid the duplicated code) would be for one to delegate to the other using `const_cast`.

Also notice the need for checking `i<0`.  That is a reason it would have been better for both `i` and `sizes` to be `unsigned` to avoid the extra check.  The optimizer should fix the apparent inefficiency of the extra check, even if you leave the type signed.  But the extra check still clutters the source code and forgetting it (as you did) is still an easy mistake.  So using `int` for values which are never correctly negative is bad practice.